# Deleting remote branch from every machine

Tags: git

I have cloned a repository on my two computers A and B. I have a branch named 'issue-1'. I deleted the local branch from both A and B. Then from computer A using `git push origin --delete issue-1` I proceeded to delete the remote branch. When I do `git branch -a`, `issue-1` is not shown among the remote branches in A. But it still shows in B. I did `git fetch` on B, and the branch still does not go away. Do I need to do remote deletion from every computer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`git fetch --prune`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#git-fetch---prune) will "remove any remote-tracking references that no longer exist on the remote".

Answer (score 0):

To add to @zigarn's answer (which deletes obsolete remote trackers but also downloads every branch on the remote repo), doing `git remote prune origin` deletes every remote-trackers from your local repository that no longer exists on the remote repository.